# Disable Automatic Comment Generation in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, comments

I've been looking for a method to disable automatic comment-generation in Eclipse (Mars Edition), and I found out that users could go into Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates and change the commenting templates as they wished, but Eclipse still automatically check-marks the "Generate comments" checkbox when creating a new file. Is there a way to disable the automatic checkmark? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out users don't have to edit all the code templates to get rid of automatic commenting!

Once navigating to the Code Templates Panel from the path described in the question, there's an option at the bottom of the panel to "Automatically add comments for new methods and types." Once you uncheck this box, Eclipse will no longer check the box to generate comments automatically when creating new files.

Comment: Interesting. Note that I don't need to do that as it is the default configuration on my Eclipse Oxygen.

Comment: Hmm. Must be because I'm using an older version of Eclipse (Mars Eclipse). Thanks for the clarification. I'll add this to my question so I don't confuse Eclipse users on different versions.

Comment: In SimRel I have that check box unchecked but Eclipse still generates javadoc for new methods.